# Create a LaTeX style table in Markdown with colors

Tags: latex, r-markdown, markdown, background-color

I want to create a table like this in `Rmarkdown`:

[image]

and [this website](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/latex_tables#) can generate codes to create a similar table in `LaTeX` which can be used in `Rmarkdown`. However, after generating the code and copying it into `Rmarkdown`, I received an error:

The **code** in `Rmarkdown`:

````
---
title: "misc"
author: "Me"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output:
  pdf_document:
    keep_tex: true
    extra_dependencies: caption
    number_sections: yes
fig_caption: yes
header-includes:
- \PassOptionsToPackage{table,xcdraw}{xcolor}
- \usepackage{xcolor}
- \usepackage{color}
- \usepackage{float}
- \usepackage{framed}
- \usepackage{fontawesome}
- \usepackage{caption}
- \usepackage{multirow}
- \usepackage[table]{xcolor}


fontsize: 11pt
urlcolor: blue
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

```{=latex}

\begin{table}[]
\begin{tabular}{|
>{\columncolor[HTML]{656565}}c |lcccc|}
\hline
\cellcolor[HTML]{656565}{\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} }                                                                                   & \multicolumn{5}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{656565}{\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} Type of Distribution}}                                                                                                                                                             \\ \cline{2-6} 
\cellcolor[HTML]{656565}{\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} }                                                                                   & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}             & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Lognormal}                          & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Exponential}                        & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Gamma}                              & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Weibull}       \\ \cline{2-6} 
\cellcolor[HTML]{656565}{\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} }                                                                                   & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Box-Cox}      & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Y}                                  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Y}                                  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{9B9B9B}\textbf{Y}} & \cellcolor[HTML]{9B9B9B}\textbf{Y} \\ \cline{2-6} 
\cellcolor[HTML]{656565}{\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} }                                                                                   & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Exponential}  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Y}                                  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Y}                                  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Y}                                  & Y                                  \\ \cline{2-6} 
\cellcolor[HTML]{656565}{\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} }                                                                                   & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Simple power} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Y}                                  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{9B9B9B}\textbf{Y}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{9B9B9B}\textbf{Y}} & \cellcolor[HTML]{9B9B9B}\textbf{Y} \\ \cline{2-6} 
\multirow{-6}{*}{\cellcolor[HTML]{656565}{\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Type of\\ transformation\end{tabular}}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Logarithmic}  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{9B9B9B}\textbf{Y}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Y}                                  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{9B9B9B}\textbf{N}} & \cellcolor[HTML]{9B9B9B}\textbf{N} \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```
````

and here the **Error** I receive:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> | >{\columncolor 
                            [HTML]{656565}}c |lcccc|
l.92 >{\columncolor[HTML]{656565}}c |lcccc|}
```

[image]

I also followed the instructions [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/484815/cellcolor-undefined-control-sequence), but didn't work and when I remove the `- \PassOptionsToPackage{table,xcdraw}{xcolor}`in the preamble I get this error:`! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package xcolor.`

Comment: I's strongly suggest to keep away from such online table generators. All these unnecessary `\multicolumn{1}`  can cause problems with alignment. Instead have a look at the new `tabularray` package. This will give much better results with respect to alignment and interaction of lines and fill colour

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that rmarkdown automatically loads the `xcolor` package way before it inserts the `header-includes`, so you don't have a chance to influence the package options there.

As a workaround, you can define `table` as class option, which will then be passed to all packages, including the `xcolor` package (and hope for the best that it won't cause any problems in other packages...)

````
---
title: "misc"
author: "Me"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output:
  pdf_document:
    keep_tex: true
    extra_dependencies: caption
    number_sections: yes
fig_caption: yes
classoption: table
header-includes:
- \usepackage{float}
- \usepackage{framed}
- \usepackage{fontawesome}
- \usepackage{caption}
- \usepackage{multirow}
fontsize: 11pt
urlcolor: blue
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

```{=latex}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\begin{tabular}{|
>{\columncolor[HTML]{656565}}c |lcccc|}
\hline
\cellcolor[HTML]{656565}{\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} }                                                                                   & \multicolumn{5}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{656565}{\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} Type of Distribution}}                                                                                                                                                             \\ \cline{2-6} 
\cellcolor[HTML]{656565}{\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} }                                                                                   & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}             & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Lognormal}                          & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Exponential}                        & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Gamma}                              & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Weibull}       \\ \cline{2-6} 
\cellcolor[HTML]{656565}{\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} }                                                                                   & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Box-Cox}      & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Y}                                  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Y}                                  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{9B9B9B}\textbf{Y}} & \cellcolor[HTML]{9B9B9B}\textbf{Y} \\ \cline{2-6} 
\cellcolor[HTML]{656565}{\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} }                                                                                   & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Exponential}  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Y}                                  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Y}                                  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Y}                                  & Y                                  \\ \cline{2-6} 
\cellcolor[HTML]{656565}{\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} }                                                                                   & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Simple power} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Y}                                  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{9B9B9B}\textbf{Y}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{9B9B9B}\textbf{Y}} & \cellcolor[HTML]{9B9B9B}\textbf{Y} \\ \cline{2-6} 
\multirow{-6}{*}{\cellcolor[HTML]{656565}{\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Type of\\ transformation\end{tabular}}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Logarithmic}  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{9B9B9B}\textbf{Y}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Y}                                  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{9B9B9B}\textbf{N}} & \cellcolor[HTML]{9B9B9B}\textbf{N} \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```
````

Comment: it works without any problem. is there any way to caption this table and reference it in the text?

Comment: @Abbas If you have a new question, please ask a new question